# Can’t access entire API docs menu on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, api, mobile-safari

This is what I see at 100% (pinched out) after expanding the menu on one of the [API documentation pages](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-close-options#filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

[image: screenshot of api doc]

In addition to it not being fully responsive (due to the “Try it” box lower on the page), I flat out can’t use the bottom part of the menu. The menu itself can’t be scrolled and using portrait orientation seems to make the menu even shorter. I’m not even sure how much of the menu is inaccessible because I don’t know what it normally looks like.